# Do you need proficiencies for riding?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, vehicles

I can't find any rules if there are specific skills needed to be able to use a mount or a vehicle. Animal Handling seems to be for when your mount is getting spooked, and vehicle proficiency seems to be only for when you're driving a vehicle under difficult conditions...

So do you not really need any particular skills in order to try riding a mount or controlling a vehicle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Anyone can use a mount or vehicle, there are no restrictions based on proficiencies**.

Ability (skill) checks only come into play when **the DM decides** it. Generally it's reasonable to assume that most characters in a medieval setting have some knowledge of mounts and vehicles.

> (***DMG p. 237***) Is a task so easy and free of conflict and stress that there should be no chance of failure?

And later on:

> (***DMG p.237***) With enough attempts and enough time, a character should eventually succeed at the task. ... However, no amount of repeating the check allows a character to turn an impossible task into a successful one.

However, when trying to do something fancy, or to prevent a mount from spooking, or say your character has never ridden a horse before, then an ability check to *Animal Handling* or *Vehicles (Land)* may be called for at the DM's discretion.

Note that these can be called with different attributes; you may need *Dexterity (Animal Handling)* to stay on a bucking mount, or *Wisdom (Animal Handling)* to calm a frightened horse. (See ***PHB p. 175*** *Variant: Skills With Different Abilities*)

Comment: I think this correct (and already-upvoted) answer would be improved with a citation to DMG p.237, which backs up everything you say. (Well, the generic skill stuff. It doesn't specifically talk about mounts and vehicles, but rather the skill system in general.)

Comment: @Randomorph I might just add a note to your second paragraph explaining that tool proficiency checks (such as *Vehicles (Land)*) cannot be made *without* proficiency.

Comment: @Randomorph Whoops, already added it in for you.  Feel free to revert or edit further.

Comment: @LegendaryDude that's alright, actually do you know what page/ book that rule about tools not being able to be used without a proficiency is on? I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Randomorph I can't find it.  Now I'm not sure if that applies; the general info on tools does say that proficiency allows you to add your proficiency bonus, and nothing about not using the tool without proficiency.  I've removed that bit until it can be verified.

Comment: @LegendaryDude I believe anyone can *use* tools and make a Tool Check, but that it's essentially just an Ability Check as you do not add proficiency bonus anyways. I don't have a citation for that right now, but I'll see if I can dig it up somewhere.

Comment: You won't find it because it's not *always* true. In fact, it's the exception, not the rule. Tool proficiency "lets you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability checks you make using the tools in your craft." (SRD p70, artisan tools) Just like all ability checks, anyone can attempt without their proficiency bonus. There are specific examples that require proficiency just to attempt, such as making antitoxin with the Herbalism kit.

Comment: @DerekStucki That's probably the type of exception I'm thinking of.  I thought there was a similar clause for vehicles or thieve's tools or something but I'm unable to check right now.  In any case, I probably incorrectly remembered the exception as the general rule.

Comment: @LegendaryDude thieve's tools are actually a great example as well. In general, proficiency with them only adds your bonus, but some specific locks, such as the "lock" or manacles from the adventuring gear list, do require proficiency to attempt. Doors (most, anyways) and traps can be attempted sans bonus by the non-proficient.

Comment: @DerekStucki also a note, that picking a lock is called out as something that cannot be performed *without* physical Thieves Tools (improvised or otherwise), but can still be attempted with Thieves Tools by the unproficient. (First sentence of p.154 in the PHB)

Comment: PHB  p.187 - "**You must be proficient** with tools related to the object you are trying to create (typically artisan’s tools)"